# Interrupt blocking code outside module using boost::thread::interrupt()

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost, activemq-classic

I have some ActiveMQ initialization code like this:

```
bool Base::init()
{
    boost::thread th(boost::bind(&Derived::init_derived, this));
    if(!th.timed_join(boost::posix_time::seconds(10)) {
        th.interrupt();
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

In child class:

```
void Derived::init_derived()
{
    try
    {
        m_session = connection.createSession(cms::Session::AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);  // Line 1
    }
    catch(boost::thread_interrupted const&)
    {
        // log error...
    }
}
```

In the caller:

```
template <typename Derived>
boost::shared_ptr<Derived> Base::create(Derived *obj)
{
    boost::shared_ptr<Derived> inst(obj);
    if(inst != nullptr && !inst->init()) {
        inst.reset();  // Line 2
    }
    return inst;
}
```

The problem is `Line 2` causes crash. If omitted, it's a memory leak.
If I replace `Line 1` with other in-module blocking code like: `for(;;){}`, it still breaks and doesn't crash. Am I not permitted to use boost thread functions outside module boundary?
How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I can reproduce the error. Mainly because I had trouble coming up with legal code that matches your snippets. (There's a typo in it, the `this` doesn't seem compatible in the `bind` and it would appear that `Base` is a [CRTP template](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pLBRW.png)).

My guess is that you fail to `join()` the local `th` thread after interrupting. See the docs:

[image]

Here's what I came up with to make your code self-contained:

**[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7ae9e24bb1b44e2e)**

```
//#define BOOST_THREAD_PROVIDES_THREAD_DESTRUCTOR_CALLS_TERMINATE_IF_JOINABLE
#include <boost/thread.hpp>
#include <iostream>

template <typename Derived> struct Base {
    virtual ~Base() = default;
    bool init();

    static boost::shared_ptr<Derived> create(Derived*);
};

struct Derived : Base<Derived> {
    void init_derived();
};

template <typename Derived> bool Base<Derived>::init() {
    boost::thread th(boost::bind(&Derived::init_derived, static_cast<Derived*>(this)));

    if (!th.timed_join(boost::posix_time::seconds(1))) {
        std::cerr << "init(): Timeout, interrupting" << std::endl;
        th.interrupt();
        //std::cerr << "init(): Interrupted, joining" << std::endl;
        //th.join();
        std::cerr << "init(): Return false" << std::endl;
        return false;
    }
    std::cerr << "init(): Return true" << std::endl;
    return true;
}

void Derived::init_derived() {
    try {
        std::cerr << "init_derived(): begin work" << std::endl;
        boost::this_thread::sleep_for(boost::chrono::seconds(2));
        // m_session = connection.createSession(cms::Session::AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
        std::cerr << "init_derived(): complete work" << std::endl;
    } catch (boost::thread_interrupted const&) {
        std::cerr << "init_derived(): interrupted" << std::endl;
        // log error...
    }
}

template <typename Derived>
boost::shared_ptr<Derived> Base<Derived>::create(Derived* obj) {
    boost::shared_ptr<Derived> inst(obj);
    return inst && inst->init() ? inst : nullptr;
}

int main() {
    auto d = Base<Derived>::create(new Derived());
}
```

Althought the output seems alright:

```
init_derived(): begin work
init(): Timeout, interrupting
init(): Return false
```

Things are not fine. The thread outlives the instance. You can see it because `init_derived()` never prints the `"init_derived(): interrupted"` trace message.

You can force your program to fail early, using

```
#define BOOST_THREAD_PROVIDES_THREAD_DESTRUCTOR_CALLS_TERMINATE_IF_JOINABLE
```

> *(Note: this is the standard behaviour for `std::thread`)*

See it **[Live](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4b6e66334a1da99f)** prints:

```
init_derived(): begin work
init(): Timeout, interrupting
init(): Return false
terminate called without an active exception
bash: line 7:  5541 Aborted                 (core dumped) ./a.out
```

There are several ways to fix it, but the simplest is quite obviously:

### Join!

Uncommenting the lines

```
    std::cerr << "init(): Interrupted, joining" << std::endl;
    th.join();
```

adds the missing join. It should be "non-blocking" assuming that the `thread_interrupted` exception is handled swiftly. See it **[Live](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/675e70f0bcc0f1ba)** printing:

```
init_derived(): begin work
init(): Timeout, interrupting
init(): Interrupted, joining
init_derived(): interrupted
init(): Return false
```

Success!

### Other Observations/Ideas

It seems like really you could use a [`packaged_task`][3]`<shared_ptr<Base>(Args...)>`. You would have the task own the shared pointer until returned, and throw on timeout.